# How to add values together inside of an object vb.net and itextsharp

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm having issues with this whole idea. What I need is to be able to add values within an obj, i.e.: (obj.issueValue). The column that is returned is a bunch of prices I need to know how to add them all together. Just to let you know, I'm doing this with iTextSharp in VB.NET. Here is the code, cuz nothing like code to help understand

```sql
SELECT
       QEE.[eventid], 
       QEE.[eventdate], 
       QEE.[employee], 
       QEE.[communication], 
       QEE.[othercommunication], 
       QEE.[issue], 
       QEE.[issuedescription], 
       QEE.[issuecomments], 
       QEE.[resolution], 
       QEE.[resolutioncomments], 
       QEE.[salesordernumber], 
       QEE.[customerpo], 
       QEE.[sostatus], 
       QEE.[customer], 
       QEE.[customername], 
       QEE.[salespersonname], 
       QEE.[isresolved], 
       QEE.[issuevalue], 
       QEE.[dateandtimeadded], 
       Datediff(day, SOR.reqshipdate, QEE.[eventdate]) AS Elapsed, 
       SOR.reqshipdate 
FROM
       [QualityTracking].[dbo].[tblqualityevententry] QEE 
INNER JOIN
       sysprocompanyc.dbo.sormaster SOR 
ON
       QEE.salesordernumber = SOR.salesorder COLLATE  latin1_general_ci_as 
WHERE  eventdate BETWEEN @from AND @to 
ORDER  BY
       eventdate ASC, 
       customername ASC, 
       salesordernumber ASC;
```

```vb
obj.issueValue = IIf(dr("IssueValue") Is DBNull.Value, 0.0, Val(dr("IssueValue")))

sumTable.AddCell(New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(obj.issue.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)))
sumTable.AddCell(New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(obj.qty, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)))
sumTable.AddCell(New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(obj.issueDescription.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)))
sumTable.AddCell(New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(obj.grandTotal, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 20, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)))
```

The obj.grandTotal is the goal. I just want the sum of the entire column to be shown, so what I need is a function to add it all together and spit out the grand total.

Comment: You can just use SUM in SQL, and do nothing on vb.

Comment: If you're pulling these values from the query, can't you store them in variables and just add those variables together?  It's not clear what you mean by "within an obj"...

Comment: they are stored but i dont know how to add stored variables together if maybe i could have help with that, that would solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try some of the Type Conversion Functions like below...

```
Debug.WriteLine(CStr(CDec("5") + CDec("5")))
```

Writes out 10

Comment: Debug.WriteLine((Convert.ToDecimal("5") + Convert.ToDecimal("5")).ToString())